# First javascript project with Durandal. Trying to get data from 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, api, durandal

So i'm working on a project where players of a game will be able to compare their performance with those of their peers at the same skill level. I can get a prototype of the code to work outside of a durandal structure, but when I try to follow along with other examples while supplying my own sources for the data, I just can't get it all together.

Here is my code:

```
define(function (require) {
var http = require('plugins/http'),
    ko = require('knockout');
var url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/',
    key = '?api_key=#################################';

return {
    name: ko.observable,
    getSummoner: function() {
        var that = this;
        if (this.name.length > 0) {
            return;
        }
        return http.jsonp(url + name + key, 'jsoncallback').then(function(response){
            that.name(response.items);
        });
    }
};
});
```

Replace the #'s with my personal API key that the host recommends I don't share. I'll supply one if necessary and just change it later.

I have 2 specific questions here:

1. I got the function structure from a tutorial. I don't know why I need to check for length with the IF statement. What is that returning exactly?
2. This api call returns a JSON object with a nested object inside. What I want, is to display the keys and values from the nested object as li's on the view. Right now I can't even get it to tell me if its actually grabbing the object in the first place.

Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
  <h2>Hello! What user would you like to investigate?</h2>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset>
       <label>Name</label>
       <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/> <!--Text input box-->
       <button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="click: getSummoner, enable: name">Click Me</button><!--This button has both a class and an ID, 
       Css is linked from index.html-->
       <ul data-bind="foreach: name">
            <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</section>
```

What I expect to see is just 1 bullet item that either says object or whatever name is fed into the input box. What I get is nothing.

The returned object (with my username attached) looks like this:

```
{"ryebrush":{"id":25500750,"name":"RyeBrush","profileIconId":551,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1426533699000}}
```

I want to be able to access the ryebrush.id, ryebrush.profileIconId, and so on and so forth. Help?

EDIT: Also, this comes pre-loaded in the input box:

```
function (b){function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.Ka(d,arguments[0])&&(c.P(),d=arguments[0],c.O()),this;a.k.zb(c);return d}var d=b;a.N.call(c);a.a.sa(c,a.m.fn);c.o=function(){return d};c.O=function(){c.notifySubscribers(d)};c.P=function(){c.notifySubscribers(d,"beforeChange")};a.s(c,"peek",c.o);a.s(c,"valueHasMutated",c.O);a.s(c,"valueWillMutate",c.P);return c}
```

Uhhhhhh.....what?

Comment: sorry, durandal is not compatible with league of legends. ;) just kidding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort of asked two questions, so I'm sort of going to give you two and a half answers.

Before we address your first question, you are using the knockout observable function incorrectly, and that is going to cause you lots of headaches. Let's fix that. The following two lines of code will both work similarly. When you call the observable function, you create a new instance of an observable. If you call it with no arguments, the value of the observable is `undefined`. Since we know you want a string here, it may be preferable to initialize it to the empty string, as in the second example.

```
name: ko.observable(),
```

or

```
name: ko.observable(''),
```

Then, we can set or retrieve the value of the observable by calling it as a function:

`that.name('value');`

and

`that.name() == 'value';`

> I got the function structure from a tutorial. I don't know why I need
>   to check for length with the IF statement. What is that returning
>   exactly?

After the if statement, you have the following line of code:

```
http.jsonp(url + name + key, 'jsoncallback')
```

If name is undefined or empty, you will attempt to make this call to one of two urls respectively:

`https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/undefined/?api_key=#`

or

`https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name//?api_key=#`

We know that both should return an error (probably a 400), so there's no point in making those calls. The if statement, when applied to a string, is true when the string is initialized and empty. Note, this will throw an error if the string is `undefined`, and that's no good.

However, the syntax is also wrong. Technically, the value of `that.name` is a function and, when treated as a string, will evaluate as

```
function (b){function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.Ka(d,arguments[0])&&(c.P(),d=arguments[0],c.O()),this;a.k.zb(c);return d}var d=b;a.N.call(c);a.a.sa(c,a.m.fn);c.o=function(){return d};c.O=function(){c.notifySubscribers(d)};c.P=function(){c.notifySubscribers(d,"beforeChange")};a.s(c,"peek",c.o);a.s(c,"valueHasMutated",c.O);a.s(c,"valueWillMutate",c.P);return c}
```

Recall from above, a much better thing to write in the if statement is

```
if (!that.name())
```

We call the function to get the value. Both `''` and `undefined` are *falsey* in javascript, and so the if statement will catch both cases and exit, which is what we want. Note it will also exit if the value of name is 0, or any other *falsey* javascript value.

> This api call returns a JSON object with a nested object inside. What
>   I want, is to display the keys and values from the nested object as
>   li's on the view. Right now I can't even get it to tell me if its
>   actually grabbing the object in the first place.

There are a number of things wrong with your view.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: name">
```

This will iterate through the value of `that.name`. If `that.name` is `'ryebrush'`, this will (I believe), iterate through each letter. That's no good. If your goal is to have a list of summoners in `that.name`, you will want to swap `ko.observable` with `ko.observableArray`. You may also want to change the name `that.name` to `that.names` to avoid confusion.

```
<li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
```

This is right *if* your array is filled with strings. `foreach` will iterate through each item in the array, and `$data` is each item. However, if the item is in fact an object, you can reference properties on the item. For example, if each item in your array is 
    {"id":25500750,"name":"RyeBrush","profileIconId":551,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1426533699000}

then, since name is a property on the object, you can reference `name` in your view

```
<li data-bind="text:name"></li>
```

Finally, you're not actually getting the data in the right place after your http call. If the response to your http call is

```
{"ryebrush":{"id":25500750,"name":"RyeBrush","profileIconId":551,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1426533699000}}
```

Then you would want to write

```
return http.jsonp(url + name + key, 'jsoncallback')
    .then(function(response){
        that.name(response["ryebrush"]);
    });
```

If the response is instead an array of items

```
[{"ryebrush":{"id":25500750,"name":"RyeBrush","profileIconId":551,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1426533699000}}]
```

Then you would want to write

```
return http.jsonp(url + name + key, 'jsoncallback')
    .then(function(response){
        that.name(response[0]["ryebrush"]);
    });
```

### Conclusion

Unfortunately, this isn't a great question. I can't tell exactly what's going on with the API you're using, so I can't tell you exactly what you should write. To accomplish what you're trying to do, you'll need to spend a little bit of time reading up on javascript, knockout, *and* durandal. Here are some good resources for each:

- [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
- [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html)
- [durandal](http://durandaljs.com/docs.html)

However, I see you're a new user. I want to encourage you not to get discouraged. It'll take a bit of time to to learn the ropes, but it's worth it. Don't give up. I hope this helps!

Comment: PLEASE make sure you upvote and accept if you've found this helpful. i would discourage you from asking a follow up to this question as this question is a bit too broad and you will probably be able to find the answer you're looking for if you spend a bit of time searching on stack overflow.

Comment: I will totally come back and do that once I have the rep for it. 

That is a really big answer, thanks for taking the time, going to dig in and fix this tonight. I'll let you know if this worked.

Comment: I'll up vote it for you. That was a kind and thoughtful answer.

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction. I'm piecing it together now, not going to just blindly copy paste from tutorials and things anymore. Thanks for being patient with me.